# Regex matching digit or specified char

Tags: regex

suppose i have this

```
sdasdas 300 qweqweqwe
```

I can match it with this regex `(\d{2,4})`
But how do I match it if one of digits is 'O' not 0 ?(for example 3O0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough. Change the character class to include `O` (both cases) as well:

```
([\doO]{2,4})
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xO7dW9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just put `\d`, Uppercase O and lowercase o inside the character class.

```
[\doO]{2,4}
```

**OR**

Use `i` modifier to turn  off the case sensitive mode.

```
/[\do]{2,4}/i
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/13)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a number with 'o' or 'O'; this will work :

```
([oO\d]+)
```